# Distributing $n$ different things among $r$ distinct groups such that all of them must get atleast $1$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> In how many ways can we arrange $7$ different things to $3$ people, such that all of them must get at least one?

We know that if we have $n$ identical items which will be distributed in $r$ distinct groups where each must get at least one then the number of way  is $\binom {n-1}{r-1}$ (i.e in this case $\binom62$. But in the question it is said that $7$ DIFFERENT things then what will be the approach?

**MY TRY ::**

At first selecting $1$ by $1$ for each $3$ people so that each get at least one : $\binom71 \times \binom 61 \times \binom 51$
Now each of $4$ can go to any of $3$ so :$3^4$ ways, so $\binom71\times\binom61\times\binom51\times (3^4)$

**MY TRY #2 ::**

total possibilities - {any one get $0$  $(0,6,1)(0,5,2)(0,4,3)$} - {any two get $0$ $ (0,0,7)(0,7,0)(7,0,0)$}
so

$$3^7 - {\left(\binom{7}{6} + \binom {7}{5} + \binom {7}{4}\right)\times 3!} - 3$$

Comment: You are double counting. For example, if objects 1,2,3,4,5,6, and 7 are allocated among A, B, and C. You are counting one way in which 1,2,3 are assigned to A, B, and C, respectively and then 4,5,6, and 7 go to A. But you also count the possibility in which 4,2,3 are first assigned to A,B, and C and then 1,5,6,7 go to A.

Comment: then how should i do this???what is the correct way???

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's actually helpful here to generalize the problem to distributing $n$ different objects to $3$ people (with $n\ge3$ so that each person can be guaranteed getting at least one item).  If you disregard the requirement that each person get at least one item, then you get the overestimate $3^n$.  From this, let's subtract the number of ways you can pick one person to *not* get any items, distributing the rest to the other two, giving

$$3^n-3\cdot2^n$$

But this now *under*-estimates because you're now doublecounting occasions when *two* people fail to receive any items.  So we need to add back in the number of ways this can happen, producing

$$3^n-3\cdot2^n+3\cdot1^n$$

As a sanity check, consider the case $n=3$, where there are clearly $6$ ways to assign an item to each person:

$$3^3-3\cdot2^3+3=27-24+3=6$$

For $n=7$, the formula gives

$$3^7-3\cdot2^7+3 = 2187-3\cdot128+3=1806$$

The general principle here is known as [inclusion-exclusion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inclusion-ExclusionPrinciple.html).  Note that it gives the correct answer, $0$, even for $n=1$ and $2$.

Comment: is there any mistake in my second try @barry cipra

Comment: @RitabrataGautam, your second try looks perfectly fine.  However, it's worth comparing its approach to the formula in my answer for values of $n$ larger than $7$, say $n=20$.

Answer (score 2):

In any distribution let there be groups $z_1, z_2, z_2,...,z_r$ and consider the distribution where blanks are allowed.

The total number of these are $ r^n$.
The number in which $z_1$ is blank is
$$(r-1)^n$$
$\therefore$ the number in which $z_1$ is not blank is ,
$$r^n-(r-1)^n$$
of these last,the umber in which $z_2$ is blank, is
$$(r-1)^n-(r-2)^n$$
$\therefore$, the number in which $z_1$ and $z_2$ are not blank,is
$$r^n-2(r-1)^n+(r-2)^n$$
If we keep doing this for $z^r$ groups, we will get this expression,
$$r^n-{x\choose1}(r-1)^n+{x\choose2}(r-2)^n-...+(-1)^x(r-x)^n$$
The number of distribution in which no one of x assigned groups is blank, is
when x=r, then
$$r^n-{r\choose1}(r-1)^n+{r\choose2}(r-2)^n-...+(-1)^(r-1){r\choose{r-1}}$$
$$or$$
$$\sum^{r}_{p=0} (-1)^p{{r}\choose{p}}(r-p)^n$$
$$or$$
$$Coefficient\,\,of\,\,x^n\,in\,\,n!(e^x-1)^r$$

So finally answer to you question,In how many ways can we arrange 7 different things to 3 people, such that all of them must get at least one?

--> $3^7-{3\choose1}2^7+{3\choose2}1^7-{3\choose3}0^7$
=1806

Bibliography:
Goyal, S., Dr. (n.d.). Chapter-5, Session-6, Arrangement in groups,Multinomial Theorem, Multiplying Syntetically. In Skill in Mathematics - Algebra for JEE Main and Advanced 2020. Arihant.

Answer (score -4):

Check [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29). Say you want to distribute $k$ items among $n$ people, no other restrictions. This means you have to chop a string of $k$ items (stars, $*$) into $n$ stretches, one to each person (with bars, $|$). This requires $n - 1$ bars. So you have a string of $n + k - 1$ stars-and-bars, of which $n - 1$ are bars, so the number of ways to do this is:

$$\binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1}$$

If you restrict each one to get at least one item, it means you first distribute $n$ items, one to each, and then you get to distribute $k - n$ among the $n$ people with no restrictions, for a number of ways (by the above):

$$\binom{k - n + n - 1}{n - 1} = \binom{k - 1}{n - 1}$$

Comment: This will surely work for 'k' identical items. Does this work for 'k' distinct items ?